# Result of accessing element beyond the array

Tags: c++, arrays

During the recruitment, I was given a test with several questions (multiple choice), this is one of them:

What will happen when you will try to compile and run a program containing  this code fragment?

```
char str[] = "abc";
char c = str[3];
```

- a) the program results may be unexpected
- b) the program won't compile
- c) the program may experience a runtime error
- d) variable `c` will store unknown value
- e) variable `c` will store `'\0'`

Comment: @Cyber:  Huh, what?  String "abc" has elements `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`.  element `[3]` is well defined as `\0`.

Comment: That was a multiple choice test.

Comment: @abelenky You are correct, I had a brainfart. The length of `str` is indeed 4 so `[3]` is a valid index.

Comment: @user3365101:  If this is a *"surprisingly tough question"* for you, please do not apply for programming jobs.  Take another class, or practice on your own until thinking through these becomes second-nature.

Comment: @abalenky, I was applying for an intern, not a job.

Comment: @abalenky, also, I am learning, and that's why I asked this question. I thought asking questions is a good way to learn. Even @Cyber got confused at first. That's why it's `surprisingly tough`.

Comment: I am not critiquing your asking a question.  You are welcome to ask questions and learn here.  However, I do not think its a good idea to apply for jobs or internships if this is representative of your knowledge.  I expect interns should be beyond this level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

***E: variable c will store '\0'***

The reasoning is:

```
char str[] = "abc";
```

is completely equivalent to :

```
char str[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

because the compiler puts in a `\0` when you declare a string.

That array has 4 elements, numbered `[0]` to `[3]`.
Element `[3]` of that array has value `\0`.

Comment: There was comment suggesting it would couse UD, and that guy was so confident I was in doubt about my programming skills... Thanks for answering to this obvious question.